# How to create more than one index page in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, indexing, partials

I have two different plans (plan with an ID of 1 and plan with an ID of 2). I've created a partial for each to show on the home page based on which plan the user is logged in as. I would like to create two different index pages for each plan to be directed to.

Plan ID 1 users need to be directed to an index of users with a plan ID of 2, and plan ID 2 users need to be directed to an index of users with a plan ID of 1. Here's the part of the code that controls this feature. How can I create an index feature which sends plan ID 1 and plan ID 2 user to different pages after click on the relative partial?

**pages/home.html.erb**

```
 <div class="col-md-6">
        <% if current_user.plan.name == "mentor" %>
          <%= render partial: "pages/mentor" %>
        <% else %>
          <%= render partial: "pages/mentee" %>
        <% end %>
  </div>
```

**pages/_mentee.html.erb**

```
<div class="well">
    <h2 class="text-center">Mentor Community</h2>
    <h4 class='text-center'>Get the support you need.</h4>
    <br><%= link_to "Find a Mentor", "#", class: 'btn btn-default btn-lg btn-block' %>
</div>
```

**pages/_mentor.html.erb**

```
<div class="well">
    <h2 class="text-center">Mentee Com</h2>
    <h4 class='text-center'>Give the support that's needed.</h4>
    <br><%= link_to "Find a Mentee", "#", class: 'btn btn-default btn-lg btn-block' %>
</div>
```

Comment: hey kim. you can either use a conditional like yesterday, or you can try and use the concept of namespacing. Namespacing will especially help if the Index is not the only part of your application that will differ according to plan.

Comment: @anthony...I'm new. Would you please explain what you've done and why? Thanks

Comment: @SunnyK...for now the only difference is that I need to have mentors being able to search the mentee index and the mentees being able to search the mentor index. So if conditionals will solve my issue, where should they be placed? inside the existing one or should they be separate?

Comment: in that case, create two partials and render them accordingly, just like you are doing above.

Comment: @SunnyK: for example: <%= render partial: "pages/mentor pages/index_mentor" %> and <%= render partial: "pages/mentee pages/index_mentee" %>

Comment: I don't understand. by index, do you mean the search only? Is the index an entirely different page? or do you want it as a search in the existing page? or...?

Comment: Think of a dating site. Women complete a profile and then are sent to a part of the site to view a list which containers men's profiles. She can then click on the ones which interest her. I was just using index as a naming convention, something that I could remember what it was

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97802/discussion-between-sunnyk-and-kim).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this:

```
#config/routes.rb
root "pages#home"
resources :plans, only: :show #-> url.com/plans/1

#app/controllers/plans_controller.rb
class PlansController < ApplicationController
   def show
      @plan = Plan.find params[:id]
   end
end

#app/views/plans/show.html.erb
<% @plan.users.each do |user| %>
   <%= user.name %>
<% end %>
```

> after click on the relative partial

You could send users to the specific plan page by using the following:

```
#app/views/pages/home.html.erb
<% @plans.each do |plan| %>
   <%= link_to plan.id, plan %>
<% end %>
```

---

There is *so much* more you need to consider, but for now, the above should help you get an understanding on the overall structure.

Let me explain a little on how you need to adapt your thinking (this might seem off topic, but will help you profusely, I guarantee it)...

[image]

The above is how Rails is *meant* to work -- it takes a request from the user, matches it to a *controller* action, and then populates it with *model* data.

The correct way for Rails to work is with something called [*object orientated programming*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming) - each time you initiate an action / request, it has to invoke & manipulate *objects* of data.

Whilst this may seem complicated, the sooner you get your head around it, the quicker you'll be able to make much more intricate rails applications.

--

Your question implies that you've not considered the full potential of a data-driven rails application.

Not that it matters, but if you changed your approach so that you got rid of `pages` and instead had `plans` with `users`, you'd be able to have as many plans as you required.

That is the correct way to think about programming (to make a *system*, not just a quick fix), which you can then use to expand the functionality as you need.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to walk me through this. I'm following a tutorial which set things up this way. These questions are coming up because I need to change it to fit my needs and I'm starting to see how it could be improved upon. Someone exactly worked with me last night to create namespaces for the plans which took care of this issue entirely. :-)

Answer (score -1):

A good way to remove the conditional would be using the plan name to find the partial. It would be something like this

```
<div class="col-md-6">
  <%= render partial: "pages/#{current_user.plan.name}" %>
</div>
```

But you need to make sure that each plan has its correct partial file. Otherwise you'll get a rendering error, because the partial isn't found.